# If $(1+x+x^2)^n = C_0 + C_1x + C_2 x^2...$, then find $C_0C_1 -C_1C_2 + C_2C_3...$

Tags: binomial-theorem

$$(1+x+x^2)^n = C_0 + C_1 x + C_2 x^2...C_n x^n$$

And
$$(1-\frac 1x +\frac{1}{x^2})^n = C_0 -\frac{C_1}{x}+\frac{C_2}{x^2}...$$

So if we multiply, the two equations, the given series will be obtained by the coefficient of $x^{-1}$ on the LHS.

The LHS$$-(\frac{x^4+x^2 +1}{x^2})^n$$
The given answer is 0, but I don’t understand how $x^{-1} $ can have coefficient 0. If it is, how do I prove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
 (1+x+x^2)(1-\frac 1x +\frac{1}{x^2}) = x^2 + 1 + \frac{1}{x^2}
$$
so that
$$
(1+x+x^2)^n(1-\frac 1x +\frac{1}{x^2})^n = (x^2 + 1 + \frac{1}{x^2})^n
$$
contains only even powers of $x$. In particular, the coefficient of $x^{-1}$ is zero.

Comment: I know it’s very obvious anecdotally, but how do I prove it? Multinomial or binomial theorem?

Comment: @Aditya: You can write it as $P(x^2)/(x^{2n})$ where $P$ is the polynomial $P(u) = (u^2+u+1)^n$. Substituting $x^2$ in a polynomial gives an expression with only even powers of $x$.